# List of columns per table

Tags: amazon-redshift

This query is working as expected:

```
select nspname, relname, max(attnum) as num_cols
from pg_attribute a, pg_namespace n, pg_class c
where n.oid = c.relnamespace and  a.attrelid = c.oid
and c.relname not like '%pkey'
and n.nspname not like 'pg%'
and n.nspname not like 'information%'
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

nspname | relname  | num_cols
--------+----------+----------
public  | category |        4
public  | date     |        8
public  | event    |        6
public  | listing  |        8
public  | sales    |       10
public  | users    |       18
public  | venue    |        5
```

But how do I get the list of columns per table?
Expected output:

```
nspname | relname  | num_cols
--------+----------+----------
public  | category | col1, col2, col3, col4
public  | date     | col1, col2, col3, col4 ..., col8
```

Mysql has group_concat function that would apply here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html

The following query mentioned on that page does not return any rows for me.

```
select distinct attrelid, rtrim(name), attname, typname
from pg_attribute a, pg_type t, stv_tbl_perm p
where t.oid=a.atttypid and a.attrelid=p.id
and a.attrelid between 100100 and 110000
and typname not in('oid','xid','tid','cid')
order by a.attrelid asc, typname, attname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include all the schemas that you want to look at in search path.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html

```
set search_path to '$user', public, enterprise;
```

Redshift without the schemas in your user id's search path cant show you the columns. For accessing table structure you may want to have **usage** rights on the schema too.